# JPA mapping for one to many with inheritance mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, annotations

I have one scenario.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "someTable")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "someDisc")
public abstract class AbstractClass{}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class Child1 extends AbstractClass{
}

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class Child2 extends AbstractClass{
}
```

Now in 3rd table I want something like this

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ThridTable{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foreinKeyCol", nullable = false)
    @OrderColumn(name = "orderCol")
    private List<Child2> child2 = new ArrayList<>();


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foreinKeyCol", nullable = false)
    @OrderColumn(name = "orderCol")
    private List<Child1> child1 = new ArrayList<>();

//more setters/getters
}
```

now while it persists well and values are getting saved correctly in the table. The problem I face while fetching object using ThridTable object. The generated query doesn't ditinguish between two instances ie child1 and child2 in same table and tries to update object of child2 in child one.

Comment: You can't use the same column to map two different associations. Use a different column for each association.

Comment: @JBNizet  :can we specify any way or any kind of mapping that force hibernate to query by specifying descriminator column value also? currently only JoinColumn value is getting specified.

Comment: @JBNizet don't you think it is a JPA bug?

Comment: @JBNizet one more thing. providing two different columns will not help. so having two different column will not help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you're using hibernate you can add a `@Where` condition to the `@OneToMany` Mappings.

E.g:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "foreinKeyCol", nullable = false)
@OrderColumn(name = "orderCol")
@Where(clause="someDisc=1")
private List<Child1> child1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

have a look at the api:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html

and:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection

Comment: Is there any way or technique to do this with pure JPA?